# Which summary statistics are always nonnegative? [just for fun]

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Which summary statistics are always nonnegative?

So far, the only ones I can think of are range and standard deviation/variance (which are positive except in trivial cases).

Comment: Adding to @Kurtosis' list (+1): coefficient of determination; coefficient of variation; estimate of a probability / proportion; standard error; various indexes of similarity; sample mean, median, mode of distribution with non-negative support (binomial, Poisson, geometric, hypergeometric; exponential, gamma, beta, Rayleigh, Weibull, Pareto, etc.).

Comment: The exponential of any summary statistic is a non-negative summary statistic.   If we stipulate $\log(0)=-\infty$ and allow $-\infty$ as a possible value, then the log of any non-negative summary statistic is a summary statistic.  Thus, your question is tantamount to asking for an enumeration of *all* summary statistics.  That's beyond the capacity of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Range, IQR, and really any quantile interval lengths;
- standard deviation/variance, kurtosis (not excess kurtosis), and all other even-power moments; and,
- likelihood and other chi-squared statistics (e.g. Wilk's lambda).